# Error: Not enough space to load specified image

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have a Lenovo Intel Atom n270 laptop. It ha Windows XP and I want to install Ubuntu on it without deleting or affecting the Windows system. For the installation I am following [this spanish guide](http://www.identi.li/index.php?topic=96247).

I have already defragmented my HDD (Although Windows still complains that some files need defragmentation) and even did a backup copy of everything.

I have identified that my processor is 32-bit so I downloaded the 32-bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 for this laptop. I then downloaded PendriveLinux and followed the steps provided by it to install the ISO image of Ubuntu into a 4GB pen drive. Rebooted the computer, changed the booting sequence and the boot menu for Ubuntu started from the pen drive. That is where the problem first appeared. Anytime I tried to either install or test Ubuntu from the menu I got the same error:

```
Not enough space to load specified image
```

After this and without knowing, I turned the computer off, took out the pen drive and tried to turn it on again. But now when Windows starts I get a blue screen that says that Windows has found an error and needs to shutdown to prevent damage.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand, you have too little memory for the Ubuntu image to load. By since your laptop has 1GB of RAM I found it odd. If you can verify that you actually have 1GB of RAM then please run an app that can check your memory for corruption.

The fact that the installer fails in that part and Windows gives you a blue screen memory error might be signs that you have corrupted memory in your computer. This of course might not be the case but if you still want to go through with the installation then I would recommend the following steps:

1. Download the Ubuntu image again.
2. Do not use PenDriveLinux. Instead, burn the image in a CD/DVD in another computer.
3. Format the pen drive and copy the Ubuntu ISO image to the pen drive.
4. Boot in another computer from that LiveCD or LiveDVD that you burned.
5. Insert the pen drive and copy the Ubuntu ISO image from it to the LiveCD/LiveDVD desktop.
6. Open DASH in the LiveCD/LiveDVD desktop session and type `Startup Disk Creator`. you should see an app that looks like a hard drive with the Ubuntu logo on it. Run this app.
7. Follow the steps there to make a Pen Drive bootable with Ubuntu. Remember that the Ubuntu image is on the Desktop.
8. If everything is ok you should have a normal, Ubuntu made pen drive that you can insert into your laptop to test Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I'll need to restore windows first, then I'll try this option